# CSS Animations (flip) won't work in Safari

Tags: css, css-animations

I got this CSS Animation that flips an image to another image which is awesome. But for some reason it won't work in Safari? Anybody got a clue why?

Check out code below or this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hpnmnL11/

Code:

```
<body>
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
<div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
       <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/332">
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/331">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes flip {
from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); transform: rotateY(0deg); }
to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); transform: rotateY(180deg); }
}

@keyframes flip {
from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); transform: rotateY(0deg); }
to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); transform: rotateY(180deg); }
}


/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
perspective: 1000;
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
width: 600px;
height: 332px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
transition: 1s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
position: relative;
-webkit-animation-name: flip;
animation-name: flip;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
animation-delay: 3s;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
backface-visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
background: white;
z-index: 2;
/* for firefox 31 */
transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
background: white;
}
```

Thank you all!
/Ohio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add -webkit- vendor prefix here:

```
.front, .back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work :( Still the same in effect, the image only turn mirrored in Safari instead of showing the "back".

Comment: Hmm it worked for me. What version of Safari do you have?

Comment: I added -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden as I posted. It is strange. It should work without it. Apparently Safari is new IE :(